# Aggregating a pandas dataframe using groupby, then using apply.... but how to then add the output back into original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I have some data with 4 features of interest: `account_id`, `location_id`, `date_from` and `date_to`. Each entry corresponds to a period where a customer account was associated with a particular location.

There are some pairs of `account_id` and `location_id` which have multiple entries, with different dates. This means that the customer is associated with the location for a longer period, covered by multiple consecutive entries.

So I want to create an extra column with the total length of time that a customer was associated with a given location. I am able to use `groupby` and `apply` to calculate this for each pair (see code below).. this works fine but I don't understand how to then add this back into the original dataframe as a new column.

`lengths = non_zero_df.groupby(['account_id','location_id'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.date_to.max() - x.date_from.min())`

Thanks

Comment: You have an array-like (`pd.Series` or `np.ndarray` object), in the correct shape, and want to add it as a column? If that's the case, `my_df['new_column_name'] = array_like_object`. Or use the `pd.DataFrame.assign` method. Or the shape isn't compatible? I'd recommend providing a Minimal and Verifiable Example (with data), and to ask programming questions to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Mephy is right that this should probably go to StackOverflow.

You're going to have a shape incompatibility because there will be fewer entries in the grouped result than in the original table.  You'll need to do the equivalent of an SQL left outer join with the original table and the results, and you'll have the total length show up multiple times in the new column -- every time you have an equal (account_id, location_id) pair, you'll have the same value in the new column. (There's nothing necessarily wrong with this, but it could cause an issue if people are trying to sum up the new column, for example)

Check out [pandas.DataFrame.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (you can also use merge).  You'll want to join the old table with the results, on (account_id, location_id), as a left (or outer) join.